# What is the standard SQL Query to retrieve the intersection of tables?

Tags: sql

Selecting the union:

```
select * from table1 
union 
select * from table1_backup
```

What is the query to select the intersection?

Comment: Intersection based on every field or just the key?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2005 or some other DBMS?

Comment: Trying to be cross-db compliant. Mainly focusing on MySQL and SQLServer.

Answer (score 9):

In SQL Server [intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)

> ```
> select * from table1 
> intersect
> select * from table1_backup
> ```

Comment: Shoot, so that's just a SQL Server answer, is there no SQL Server/MySQL cross-db query?

Comment: According to blog posts and listservs from 2005 I found on google, MySQL doesn't support the straight intersect notation, and instead suggests Inner Joins or subqueries.

Comment: The question doesn't state that a MySQL solution is required.

Be aware that an Interest is also an implicit DISTINCT (same as UNION and MINUS)

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT *
FROM table1_backup
WHERE table1.pk = table1_backup.pk)
```

works

Comment: This looks like a good answer, but not as abstract as the one I accepted.  It's probably faster too.

Comment: For my purposes, I didn't need the where clause.

Comment: You need a WHERE clause otherwise it doesn't make sense. You'll just return all rows from table1 if any rows exist in table1_backup. Otherwise you'll get zero rows.

Answer (score 2):

For questions like this, I tend to go back to this visual resource:

[A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 1):

inner join i think:
suppose T1 and T2 have the same structure:

select T1.* from
T1 inner join T2 on T1.pkField = T2.pkField

Comment: The union is useful because it doesn't add a extra fields. It treats two tables as the same table when used. I want the same thing, except I want I to see which records are exactly the same in case something messed up in running a backup.

Answer (score 1):

"intersect" is also part of standard SQL.

Inner join gives a different answer.

Comment: So what would the query be?
select * from table1 intersect select * from table2 gives me an error in mysql

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution for mySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
id INT(10),
fk_id INT(10),
PRIMARY KEY (id, fk_id),
FOREIGN KEY table1(id) REFERENCES another_table(id),
FOREIGN KEY table1(fk_id) REFERENCES other_table(id)
);

SELECT table1.* FROM table1 as t0
INNER JOIN table1 as a ON (t0.id = a.id and fk_id=1)
INNER JOIN table1 as b ON (t0.id = b.id and fk_id=2)
INNER JOIN table1 as c ON (t0.id = c.id and fk_id=3)
ORDER BY table1.id;
```

Basically you have an table of mathematical subsets (ie. 1={1, 2 ,3}, 2={3, 4, 2}, ... , n={1, 4, 7}) with an attribute id, which is the set number, and fk_ id, which references a PRIMARY KEY of a table of elements, the superset (meaning possible values for the numbers in the curly braces). For those not mathematically inclined, let's pretend you have a table, 'other_ table', which is a list of items, and another table, 'another_ table', which is a list of transaction numbers, and both tables form a many-to-many relationship, thus producing 'table1'. now let's pretend you wanted to know the id's in 'another_ table' which had items 1, 2, and 3. that's the query to do it.

Answer (score 0):

An intersect on two identical tables a and b can be done in this manner:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM a INNER JOIN b
USING (id, name)
```

Answer (score -1):

subqueries?! really?

to get the intersection of table1 and table2:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.pk=table2.pk;
```

Comment: That's not the intersection, that's just a join.  Unions work with two identical datasets, I was looking for a related function.  You're right though, you could join on each field.  The -1 is just for using the Lord's name in vain.

Answer (score -4):

```
select distinct * from (select * from table1 union select * from table1_backup)
```

Comment: Excellent, this is the query I was looking for, stackoverflow is awesome, only took 5 minutes and was a lot more fun than Google-ing. 

This answer is perfect for me in every way except it needs to have "as table_x" at the end to not get a key violation in my version of SQL.

Comment: This doesn't return an intersect... it returns every single row in each of the tables, and filters out duplicates.